# NSManagedObject is not deleted unless a fetch is requested

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am deleting a managed object from core data like this:

```
[item.managedObjectContext deleteObject:item];
```

(Note that this item is created, but not saved at this point.)

Trying to fix a bug, I wanted to confirm that the item was indeed deleted. First, since every 'item' belongs to a 'list', I logged the count of list.items before and after. There was no change. Suspect.

To be doubly sure, I added a fetch request before and after the deletion, and logged the total number of items in the context. This is where it gets weird.

I found that the very act of executing the fetch removed my initial bug. In other words, if I execute a fetch before and after the deletion, I can clearly see that the number of items in the context is reduced by one. However, without this fetch, the item is not deleted (or at least not immediately).

Does anyone have some insight into what is happening here?

Comment: are you doing a [managedObjectContext save] operation?

Comment: No - there is no need since the context was not saved when the item was added. Basic flow here is that the user wants to add an item, so I create it (without saving) and present a modal. If the user adds the item, I save the context. If they cancel, I just delete the object (no saves occur). This happens using delegates and is modeled on an Apple demo I found.

Comment: this is your problem, @Abizem is correct.  These inserted and deleted objects exist in memory but are flagged as inserted or deleted objects, until you save the deleted objects are still there (but flagged as pending deletion)

Comment: Except it seems they are deleted as soon as I execute a fetch (still with no save beforehand)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `deleteObject` method doesn't actually remove the object - it marks it for deletion. The changes aren't actually made until the changes are committed.

**Edited to add**

To expand on the answer in response to the comments:

If you want to know if the context has changed so you know when to fire off a fetch request then you can register to observe the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` which is sent when an object in the context is sent a deleteObject message.

Comment: But the object is never saved in the first place - it is added and removed with no save operations in between.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If it hasn't been persisted, it is simply discarded from the managed object context, but the result is the same; deletion doesn't actually remove the object.

Comment: When is it actually deleted then (aside from an explicit save)? The first time someone queries the context? Is that why it is deleted simply by me executing a fetch request immediately after?

Comment: There's no point deleting it until you need to do anything with the data. It means you can do multiple deletions, but it's not until you actually ask for the state of the store that any deletions are made, and associated changes propagated through the store.

Comment: Got it - many thanks. My problem is that after I delete the object and return to my view, it wants to check how many items exist in the list. It is doing this by querying list.items, which (I guess) doesn't ask for the state of the store. I need to either re-fetch (instead of looking at list.items) or, probably more simply, just save the context . It just feel weird to add an item, delete it, and have to save my context.